# How can I tell if a port is accessible on an Ubuntu machine?

Tags: ubuntu, munin

I have an Ubuntu machine, and I've been trying to set up Munin on port 4949.  I have it running, and I can connect to port 4949 from the local machine, but connections from external machines keep timing out.  I've already set `allow ^.*$` in the configuration, so it shouldn't refuse any connections.

If I run `lsof` I get:

```
deployer@rc:~$ sudo lsof | grep munin
/usr/sbin 31863       root    2w      REG              202,1     78531     189176 /var/log/munin/munin-node.log
/usr/sbin 31863       root    3r      REG              202,1      6778     591661 /usr/sbin/munin-node
/usr/sbin 31863       root    4w      REG              202,1     78531     189176 /var/log/munin/munin-node.log
/usr/sbin 31863       root    5u     IPv6           42450001       0t0        TCP *:munin (LISTEN)
```

I can't tell if it's a firewall issue or not.  How can I tell if inbound connections are successfully reaching port 4949?

Comment: Which version of ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Ubuntu, you likely have ufw installed to manage your firewall.  What's the output of

```
sudo ufw status
```

If you need to add a rule to allow inbound to TCP port 4949, you can do so with the following:

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.0.1 port 4949
```

You can also check to see what interfaces you're listening on with

```
sudo netstat -tanp
```

Also, nmap is a great tool to check from another machine what ports are open, but if it's not a LAN setup you need to be careful scanning a public IP.

Comment: This is running in the cloud, so Rackspace is running the firewall.  ufw is inactive.

Comment: Ah, I see -- what's the netstat output?  How do you open or close ports, or otherwise manage the firewall?

Comment: When we need to open and close ports, we call them on the phone and put in a support request.  They claim they can see packets hitting the machine, but since Munin isn't responding I don't necessarily believe them, and was trying to verify.

Comment: OK, so does netstat list the port?  Your lsof output shows it listening on IPv6, does it have an IPv4 address assigned as well or only IPv6?

Comment: The only listing for munin in netstat is `tcp6 0 0 :::4949                 :::* LISTEN 31863/munin-node`

Comment: Looks fine -- to check the firewall issue, can you telnet to the port from a remote system?

Comment: No.  It times out.

Comment: Tends to sound like a firewall issue to me then.  You could try running tcpdump on the host while you try to connect via telnet from the remote system, and seeing what comes through.  Give that info to your hosting if nothing appears to even be hitting the server.  Only other option would be that the port is being blocked on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

This will show what daemons are listening on what ports.

```
# lsof | grep TCP | grep LISTEN
```

You'll want to see *:4949 to confirm that Munin is bound on all interfaces.

Comment: This does not report anything on 4949, but I can telnet to localhost on port 4949 and get the Munin service all the same.

Comment: Does it show anything for munin? Can you add the output of the command suggested?

Comment: I added the lsof output to the question.

Comment: That looks fine, assuming you have `munin           4949/tcp                # Munin Graphing Framework` in `/etc/services`.

Comment: I have `munin 4949/tcp lrrd # Munin` so I suppose that's fine?

Comment: Sounds like you're imapacted by this bug with Munin.  http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=643654